# PRESTASHOP 1.5.3.1 - Find products pictures module

Tags: image, module, zooming, prestashop

I am a prestashop beginner. I would like to integrate a plugin to zoom product pictures.
But i don't find where i can integrate my code.
Where can i find the products's pictures module ?

I am searching, but if someone could help me, it would save time.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of Prestashop 1.5 is the previous release of Prestashop? The actual release Prestashop 1.6 has a javascript library to zoom in products.

Comment: Yes, but i can't upgrade my version.

Answer (score 0):

What is your theme ? 
The product image zoom is already in default theme on Prestashop 1.4, you have just to activate in BO (params -> products).

Comment: The theme is a personal theme. 

Prestashop 1.6 is better but i can't upgrade my version. I don't start the project, I have to fix some issues.

The default zoom is already activated, it works but it doesn't works properly. I just see the picture in the same size in the zoom window.

Comment: Control your call to jqzoom in product.js. In Prestashop 1.5, the call is:

        $('#bigpic').attr('rel', $('#bigpic').attr('src').replace('large', 'thickbox'));
        $('img.jqzoom').jqueryzoom({
            xzoom: 200, //zooming div default width(default width value is 200)
            yzoom: 200, //zooming div default width(default height value is 200)
            offset: 21 //zooming div default offset(default offset value is 10)
            //position: "right" //zooming div position(default position value is "right")
        });
    }

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I will try to fix the problem.